# How can I change an input style when I click submit and the inputs are empty?

Tags: php, css

I can't change the input style when the user clicks submit and the required fields are empty.

I tried creating a div for each input and changing it in css, tried using if in CSS, tried if and elseif in php, but nothing seems to work. I really need this to work, as this is a very important school project. I hope you can help me.

PHP:

```
  function ApresentarFormulario() {
      echo '
      <div id="body">        
      <div class="signup-box">
      <br><br><br>
      <h1>SIGNUP</h1>
      <br><br>
      <form class="form_signup" method="post" action="register.php?a=register" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table>
        <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Primeiro nome: *</label>
          <input type="text" name="primeironome" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
           <label>Último nome:</label>
           <input type="text" name="ultimonome" value="">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Username: *</label>
          <input type="text" name="username" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Email: *</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" value="" required>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
          <label>Password: *</label>
          <input type="password" name="password1" value="" required>
        </td>
        <td>
          <label>Confirme a password: *</label>
          <input type="password" name="password2" value="" required>
        </td>
        </tr>
                             (...)
      </table>
<br><br>

<input type="submit" name="register" value="SIGN UP">
</form>
</div>
<br>
</div>
';
}

if($primeironome=="") {
  echo 'Primeiro nome';
  $erro = true;
}

if ($ultimonome=="") {
  echo 'Último nome';
  $erro = true;
}

if ($username=="") {
  echo 'Username';
  $erro = true;
}

if ($email=="") {
  echo 'Email';
  $erro = true;
}

if ($password1=="") {
  echo 'Password 1';
  $erro = true;
}

if ($password2=="") {
  echo 'Password 2';
  $erro = true;
}
                              (...)


if($erro)
{
  ApresentarFormulario();
  exit;
}
```

CSS:

```
div#body input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=password], input[type=tel] {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
}

.erro {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
```

I want the border-color of the required inputs to change to red when the problem is verified.

Comment: You created the CSS called `.erro` but you never attach that class to any of your html elements??

Comment: use javascript on click/submit validate and add a css class? For testing add that erro CSS class to input to see if it works, if not read about CSS first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not the correct way to do that, but you can try it.

Create an array to storage all errors.

```php
$erros = array();

if($primeironome=="")
  array_push( $erros, 'primeiro_nome');

if($ultimonome=="")
  array_push( $erros, 'ultimo_nome');
```

After that, pass the array by parameter on method.

```php
if( count( $erros ) > 0 ) {
  ApresentarFormulario( $erros );
  exit;
}
```

Check if there's a key with the input field.

```php
function ApresentarFormulario( $erros ) {
    // (...)

    $class = ( in_array( 'primeironome', $erros ) ? 'erro' : '';
    echo '<input type="text" name="primeironome" value="" class="' . $class . '" required>';

    $class = ( in_array( 'ultimonome', $erros ) ? 'erro' : '';
    echo '<input type="text" name="ultimonome" value="" class="' . $class . '" required>';

    // (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your CSS use the required selector instead of the .erro class

```
:required{
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    color: red;
    background: transparent;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I think they want to style them in the error case, so that would be `:invalid`

Comment: :invalid is type based but yeah i guess it depends on their purpose

Comment: Don’t know what you mean by “typed based”. `:invalid` on its own applies to any form control, that is in invalid state.

Comment: The result differs based on the input field type attribute value, ex: text is different than password.

Comment: What “results” are you talking about, `:invalid` is a _selector_, it _selects_ elements, it doesn’t _do_ anything with them on its own. It does not care why or how a field became invalid, only that it currently _is_.